# How to say in RegExp "contain this too"?

Tags: regex

I need to check multiple regexp in one string. Is it possible to check in one regexp? Here is important to find any order of words.

For example I looking for "quick", "jump" "lazy" in the string.

I can check it with `OR` operator. It working with `|` (pipe) character. But how can I change the `OR` to `AND` ?

I can use this with `OR`:

```
/quick|jump|lazy/
```

But I want to use something like this:

```
/quick&jump&lazy/
```

Is there any way?

Comment: So basically you want to match, what, a line in a string containing those words? Because `quick|jump|lazy` is **one** match, so the OR operator is pretty explicit here. A AND operator wouldn't be, as it would imply multiple matches.

Comment: @Kilazur I want to match two or more words in a string. And I want to match only if every words are in the strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/(?=.*quick)(?=.*jump)(?=.*lazy)/` is what you're looking for I believe

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fixed it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Even with the `.*` thrown in, this will only match words in the given order, i.e. it will match `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`, but it won't match `over the lazy dog jumps the quick brown fox`

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: No, you don't have problems of order, since you use zero-width assertions. Each words can be everywhere in the string (test it)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I stand corrected - I thought you talked about putting the `.*` between the matching groups, sorry.