# Regular expression to check path of url as well as specific parameters

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have url's like the following:

```
/home/lead/statusupdate.php?callback=jQuery211010657244874164462_1455536082020&ref=e13ec8e3-99a8-411c-be50-7e57991d7acb&status=5&_=1455536082021
```

I would like a regular expression to use in my Google analytic goal that checks to see that the request uri is /home/lead/statusupdate.php and has ref and status parameter present regardless of what order these parameters are passed and regardless of if there are extra parameters because I really just care about the 2. I have looked at these examples

[How to say in RegExp "contain this too"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886791/how-to-say-in-regexp-contain-this-too?lq=1) and [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator#469951) but I can't seem to adapt the  examples given there to work.

Im using this online tool to test http://www.regexr.com/ (perhaps the tool is the buggy one? I'l try in javascript in the mean time)

Comment: Can you please include what REGEX expressions you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
\/home\/lead\/statusupdate\.php\?(ref=|.*(&ref=)).*(&status=)
```

if the order does not matter, then add the oppostite

```
\/home\/lead\/statusupdate\.php\?(status=|.*(&status=)).*(&ref=)
```

all put together

```
\/home\/lead\/statusupdate\.php\?(((ref=|.*(&ref=)).*(&status=))|((status=|.*(&status=)).*(&ref=)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
(/home/lead/statusupdate.php?A)|(/home/lead/statusupdate.php?B)|(/home/lead/statusupdate.php?C)|(/home/lead/statusupdate.php?D)|(/home/lead/statusupdate.php?E)|(/home/lead/statusupdate.php?F)
```

Note that here A,B,C,D,E,F are notations for six different permutations for 'callback' string, 'ref' string, 'status' string and '_' string.

Answer (score 0):

Not really elegant but this works:

`\/home\/lead\/statusupdate\.php(.*(ref|status)){2}`

Looks for `/home/lad/statusupdate.php` followed by 2x any character followed by `ref` *or* `status`. Admittedly this would be a match for an url with 2x `ref` or `status` though.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ4gP6/1#javascript)